# How to insert string into a string by C the better way?

Tags: c, string, char

I want to do something from

```
char* a = "/data/cc/dd/ee/ff/1.jpg";
```

then get

```
char* b = "/data/cc/dd/ee/ff/json_1.json";
```

or

```
char *b = "/data/cc/dd/ee/1.txt";
```

It is very easy in Python but unfortunately I have to do this in C.
I did something like:

Ubuntu C

```
char classpath[4096];
char *dirc, *basec, *bname, *dname;
find_replace(path, ".jpg", ".txt", classpath);
dirc = strdup(path);
basec = strdup(path);
dname = dirname(dirc);
bname = basename(basec);
```

I know the next step should be concatenating `dname`, `'json_'` and `bname`
probably  create the final path first like char `ressultpath[4096];`
then using `strcat()`, but I want to know what is a better way to use less memory and faster since I am really not familiar with C .

Comment: Note that `strdup`, `dirname` and `basename` are platform-specific functions defined in IEEE POSIX (a document standardizing Unix-like operating systems), not ISO C. `strdup` has been in POSIX for 30 years, but `dirname` and `basename` are newer; they were added in Issue 4, around 2008.

Comment: Both [`dirname()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/dirname.html) and [`basename()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/basename.html) were in [SUS 1997](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/), and were available much sooner on many systems as they were in SVR4 and the SVID.  They were3 documented in [POSIX 2004](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) too — [`basename()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/basename.html) and [`dirname()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dirname.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard function `strrchr()` (which searches for the last instances of a character in a string) to find both the final `/` in the pathname and the final `.` in the filename component.  From the positions of those characters (if they exist), you can then calculate the starting position and length of both the directory and filename components of the path.  You can then use the `snprintf()` function with those starting position and lengths to stitch together the filename you want in your destination:

```
char classpath[4096];
const char *dir_end;
const char *name;
const char *suffix;
int dir_length;
int name_length;
int result_length;

/* Find the end of the directory component of the path, if it has one. */
dir_end = strrchr(path, '/');

if (dir_end)
{
    /* The filename starts immediately after the final / */
    name = dir_end + 1;
    /* The length of the directory component up to and including the final / */
    dir_length = dir_end - path + 1;
}
else
{
    /* No directory component, so the filename begins at the start of the path */
    name = path;
    dir_length = 0;
}

/* Find the start of the file suffix, if it has one */
suffix = strrchr(name, '.');

if (suffix)
{
    /* The length of the name not including the last . */
    name_length = suffix - name;
}
else
{
    /* No suffix at all, so the name is everything remaining */
    name_length = strlen(name);
}

result_length = snprintf(classpath, sizeof classpath, "%.*sjson_%.*s.json", dir_length, path, name_length, name);

if (result_length >= sizeof classpath)
{
    /* result was truncated */
}
```

Comment: The various length variables better were typed `size_t`.

Comment: @alk: Unfortunately the `%.*` variable precision specifiers require `int` to be passed (and `snprintf()` returns `int`).  You could test upfront to ensure the entire passed path doesn't exceed `INT_MAX` in length.